# Hololens barcode reader using UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, qr-code, barcode, hololens

Here i would like to know about reading the barcode from hololens.

```
public sealed partial class ScanQrPage : Page
{
    public bool SoftwareTriggerStarted { get; set; } = false;
    bool isSelectionChanging = false;
    public bool IsScannerClaimed { get; set; } = false;
    public bool ScannerSupportsPreview { get; set; } = false;
    ClaimedBarcodeScanner claimedScanner = null;
    static readonly Guid rotationGuid = new Guid("C380465D-2271-428C-9B83-ECEA3B4A85C1");
    BarcodeScanner selectedScanner = null;
    MediaCapture mediaCapture;
    DeviceWatcher watcher;
    ObservableCollection<BarcodeScannerInfo> barcodeScanners = new ObservableCollection<BarcodeScannerInfo>();
    DisplayRequest displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();
    public ScanQrPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector());
        watcher.Added += Watcher_Added;
        watcher.Removed += Watcher_Removed;
        watcher.Updated += Watcher_Updated;
        watcher.Start();

    }
    private async void StartSoftwareTriggerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grd_btn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        scanQr.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        if (claimedScanner != null)
        {
            await claimedScanner.StartSoftwareTriggerAsync();

            SoftwareTriggerStarted = true;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SoftwareTriggerStarted));
        }
    }
    private async void StopSoftwareTriggerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grd_btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        scanQr.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        if (claimedScanner != null)
        {
            await claimedScanner.StopSoftwareTriggerAsync();
            result.Text = "";
            SoftwareTriggerStarted = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SoftwareTriggerStarted));
        }
    }
    private async void Watcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            barcodeScanners.Add(new BarcodeScannerInfo(args.Name, args.Id));
            await SelectScannerAsync(args.Id.ToString());
        });
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private async void ClaimedScanner_DataReceived(ClaimedBarcodeScanner sender, BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            result.Text = DataHelpers.GetDataLabelString(args.Report.ScanDataLabel, args.Report.ScanDataType);
            var s2 = DataHelpers.GetDataString(args.Report.ScanData);
            var s3 = BarcodeSymbologies.GetName(args.Report.ScanDataType);
            var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            localSettings.Values["UserName"] = DataHelpers.GetDataLabelString(args.Report.ScanDataLabel, args.Report.ScanDataType);

            if (result.Text.ToString() != "Result") {
                Helper.Alert(result.Text.ToString());
            }
                //Frame.Navigate(typeof(Dashboard));
            else
                Helper.Alert("Please Scan a QR/BarCode to Login");
        });
    }
    private async Task SelectScannerAsync(string scannerDeviceId)
    {
        selectedScanner = await BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync(scannerDeviceId);

        if (selectedScanner != null)
        {
            claimedScanner = await selectedScanner.ClaimScannerAsync();
            if (claimedScanner != null)
            {
                await claimedScanner.EnableAsync();
                ScannerSupportsPreview = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedScanner.VideoDeviceId);
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ScannerSupportsPreview));
                claimedScanner.DataReceived += ClaimedScanner_DataReceived;
                if (ScannerSupportsPreview)
                    await StartMediaCaptureAsync(selectedScanner.VideoDeviceId);
            }
            else
            {
                //rootPage.NotifyUser("Failed to claim the selected barcode scanner", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //rootPage.NotifyUser("Failed to create a barcode scanner object", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }

        IsScannerClaimed = claimedScanner != null;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsScannerClaimed));

        isSelectionChanging = false;
    }
    private void Watcher_Removed(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
    {
        // We don't do anything here, but this event needs to be handled to enable realtime updates.
        // See https://aka.ms/devicewatcher_added.
    }

    private void Watcher_Updated(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
    {
        // We don't do anything here, but this event needs to be handled to enable realtime updates.
        //See https://aka.ms/devicewatcher_added.
    }
    private async Task StartMediaCaptureAsync(string videoDeviceId)
    {
        mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

        // Register for a notification when something goes wrong
        mediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;

        var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            VideoDeviceId = videoDeviceId,
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
            SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.SharedReadOnly,
        };

        // Initialize MediaCapture
        bool captureInitialized = false;
        try
        {
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
            captureInitialized = true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            //rootPage.NotifyUser("The app was denied access to the camera", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //rootPage.NotifyUser("Failed to initialize the camera: " + e.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }

        if (captureInitialized)
        {
            // Prevent the device from sleeping while the preview is running.
            displayRequest.RequestActive();

            PreviewControl.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            await SetPreviewRotationAsync(DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().CurrentOrientation);
            //IsPreviewing = true;
            //RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsPreviewing));
        }
        else
        {
            mediaCapture.Dispose();
            mediaCapture = null;
        }
    }
    private async Task SetPreviewRotationAsync(DisplayOrientations displayOrientation)
    {
        bool isExternalCamera;
        bool isPreviewMirrored;

        // Figure out where the camera is located to account for mirroring and later adjust rotation accordingly.
        DeviceInformation cameraInformation = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(selectedScanner.VideoDeviceId);

        if ((cameraInformation.EnclosureLocation == null) || (cameraInformation.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown))
        {
            isExternalCamera = true;
            isPreviewMirrored = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isExternalCamera = false;
            isPreviewMirrored = (cameraInformation.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
        }

        PreviewControl.FlowDirection = isPreviewMirrored ? FlowDirection.RightToLeft : FlowDirection.LeftToRight;

        if (!isExternalCamera)
        {
            // Calculate which way and how far to rotate the preview.
            int rotationDegrees = 0;
            switch (displayOrientation)
            {
                case DisplayOrientations.Portrait:
                    rotationDegrees = 90;
                    break;
                case DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped:
                    rotationDegrees = 180;
                    break;
                case DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped:
                    rotationDegrees = 270;
                    break;
                case DisplayOrientations.Landscape:
                default:
                    rotationDegrees = 0;
                    break;
            }

            // The rotation direction needs to be inverted if the preview is being mirrored.
            if (isPreviewMirrored)
            {
                rotationDegrees = (360 - rotationDegrees) % 360;
            }

            // Add rotation metadata to the preview stream to make sure the aspect ratio / dimensions match when rendering and getting preview frames.
            var streamProperties = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
            streamProperties.Properties[rotationGuid] = rotationDegrees;
            await mediaCapture.SetEncodingPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, streamProperties, null);
        }
    }
    private void MediaCapture_Failed(MediaCapture sender, MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs errorEventArgs)
    {

    }

    private void Back_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            Frame.GoBack();
    }

    private void ResultButton_Click(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (result.Text != "Result")
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Dashboard));
        }
    }


}
public class BarcodeScannerInfo
{
    public BarcodeScannerInfo(String deviceName, String deviceId)
    {
        DeviceName = deviceName;
        DeviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public String Name => $"{DeviceName} ({DeviceId})";
    public String DeviceId { get; private set; }
    private string DeviceName;
}



public partial class DataHelpers
{
    public static string GetDataString(IBuffer data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            return "No data";
        }

        // Just to show that we have the raw data, we'll print the value of the bytes.
        // Arbitrarily limit the number of bytes printed to 20 so the UI isn't overloaded.
        string result = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(data);
        if (result.Length > 40)
        {
            result = result.Substring(0, 40) + "...";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static string GetDataLabelString(IBuffer data, uint scanDataType)
    {
        // Only certain data types contain encoded text.
        // To keep this simple, we'll just decode a few of them.
        if (data == null)
        {
            return "No data";
        }

        // This is not an exhaustive list of symbologies that can be converted to a string.
        if (scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.Upca ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.UpcaAdd2 ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.UpcaAdd5 ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.Upce ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.UpceAdd2 ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.UpceAdd5 ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.Ean8 ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.TfStd ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.OcrA ||
            scanDataType == BarcodeSymbologies.OcrB)
        {
            // The UPC, EAN8, and 2 of 5 families encode the digits 0..9
            // which are then sent to the app in a UTF8 string (like "01234").
            return CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, data);
        }

        // Some other symbologies (typically 2-D symbologies) contain binary data that
        // should not be converted to text.
        //return string.Format("Decoded data unavailable. Raw label data: {0}", DataHelpers.GetDataString(data));
        return CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, data);
    }
}
```

> This is my code that works fine in my Windows 10 PC.
>
> When i package the same code and deployed into Hololens, I can't able
>   to read the Barcode/Qrcode.

Is there any hardware specification that i need to enable or any other that i have missed here?

Comment: Is `webcam` under Capabilities enabled? Are you using something that accesses at the same time the camera (e.g. Vuforia)?

Comment: Yes, Capabillities are enabled. No i dont use camera for any other process.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this stuff... maybe it has something to do with clipping? From how far away should your qr-code be recognized? maybe the `Near Clip` of the `Mixed Reality Camera Manager` on the camera is set too high and thats why the camera does not recognize the code?

Comment: I'm trying to do same thing, if I run a "BarcodeScanner.CheckHealth" I get the message "No Decoder" in the Hololens, for windows I have followed this: https://learn.microsoft.com/et-ee/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-camerabarcode-enable-disable?view=tfs-2017 - but not sure how to do so in Hololens

Answer (score 3):

@Nandha,

The challenge with reading barcodes with HoloLens V1 is that the camera is only capable of fixed focus when streaming the image.   It is unable to autofocus on the barcode and thus it is difficult to get the barcode into the exact focus for a successful read.  It may work with a barcode that is sufficiently large, but I would not expect it to be reliable on standard sized barcodes.  Hopefully the camera in a future version of HoloLens will have the needed auto-focus functionality for barcode decoding.

Terry Warwick, Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Hololens 2 is now capable of continuous auto focus (CAF).  So, the windows.devices.pointofservice API set for barcode reading will work adequately now with UWP apps.

- Try out Hololens 2 with [JustScanIt app](https://aka.ms/justscanit)
- It's a free demonstration of how CAF can work to scan barcodes
- It has links in the help for all associated microsoft online docs, and UWP samples.
- It uses the native industrial grade Digimarc decoder in Windows for mulitple barcode symbologies (QR, UPC, pdf417, etc.)
- Really good blog article: [Windows 10 camera-based barcode scanner](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201130-00/?p=104495)

Comment: I've tried this out on HoloLens OS build 20348.1450 but the camera doesn't focus at all. Did that work on previous versions?